# How to extract columns with a for loop?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

**Question**
If there is a matrix of MxN, how can extract all of the data based in the columns?
Im interesting to pass each column to a function and to be plotted.

if A(:) is used all the matrix is merged into a single column, (I remember this command is intended for that) but this does not serve to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab arrays use the indexing, `partOfArray = array(rows, columns)`. The variables rows and columns can be a vector (including a scalar, which is a vector of length 1) or `:` which is effectively interpreted by Matlab as meaning 'all' (e.g. `array(:,columns)` would be all rows of the selected columns).

Alternatively, Matlab also allows linear indexing, in which `array(aNumber)` counts in order from `array(1,1)` first by rows, then by columns. e.g. if array is 2x4, `array(5)` is equivalent to `array(2,1)`. When you call `A(:)` Matlab interprets that as using linear indexing to access all elements in the array, hence merging the matrix into a single column.

To access each column vector in a for loop, in this case printing it out, use:

```
A = magic(4)
numColumnsInA = size(A,2);
for i=1:numColumnsInA
    disp(A(:,i))
end
```

You can find more information about indexing in Matlab here: [Array Indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html)